# capturing a string return value from one function in bash into another

Tags: bash

I am trying to send a string as a return value from a function which is being called by another function in a different file. One sources the other.

The code is, like so:

```
#####################################################  
##filename: conf_abc.menu
#######################################################
#!/bin/bash
source <path>/conf_pqr.menu

function abc () {
    var=$(call_pqr)
    echo ${var}
}
##Calling function abc
abc

#########################################################
##filename: conf_pqr.menu
########################################################
#!/bin/bash

RET_VAL=""
function get_intf() {
   cmd=`some command`
   RET_VAL=${cmd}
}

function call_pqr () {
   comm=$(array of choices)
   for choice in $comm
   do
      case $choice in
      IF)get_intf;
         echo "$RET_VAL";;
      esac
   done
}
```

I expect to see the choice from the array in "var" of function abc().
But the "echo ${var}" in conf_abc.menu does not print anything.

I run the script by doing:
./conf_abc.menu

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the `IF)` case is being hit? Add `echo "$RET_VAL" >&2` to confirm that it is and that `$RET_VAL` contains what you think it does. BTW, it would help us if you created a [mcve], which you could do by replacing "array of choices" and "some command" with actual values.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the main script and see what commands are *actually* being run when your script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I found that when the return is called from the function, the entire output from echo is captured into the return variable. I then filtered the output using ">&2". I find that I do get the proper return string.
This I found from: 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11758368/shell-script-function-return-a-string](http://shell%20script%20function%20returning%20string)

I have put in a minimal example here:

```
##**file: vlan_menu.sh**
#!/bin/bash
source <path>/ifs_menu.sh

function conf_vlan () {
    echo "Calling function if_menu" >&2
    local output1=$(if_menu);
    echo "printing result" >&2
    ENET1="${output1}"
    echo "ENET1 is= "${ENET1}"" >&2
}
conf_vlan; --> calling the main function

##**file: ifs_menu.sh**
#!/bin/bash

RET_VAL=""

function get_if() {
    PI=$1
    local var1=$(shell command)
    if [ ! -z "${PI}" ]
    then
        local var2=<do something with var1>
    else
        local var2=<do something with var1>
    fi
    local cmd=$(start shell utility)
    RET_VAL=${cmd}
}

function if_menu() {
comm=(1 2 3 4 5)
for choice in ${comm}
do
    case $choice in
    1) echo "IF" >&2;
       get_if "";
       echo "${RET_VAL}";;

    2) echo "SF" >&2;
        get_if $1;
        echo "${RET_VAL}";;
    esac
done
}
```

After running "vlan_menu.sh" script file, the value of "ENET1" is the same as "RET_VAL" which is what I wanted to see.

-rsmitha.